# Error 1064(42000) While Taking Backup Of All Database With Mysqldump In Wamp Server Mysql Command Line

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp, wampserver

When I'm trying to take backup all databases in wamp server mysql console. I'm getting mysql error message.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql Server versuib fir tge right syntax to user near 'mysqldump -uroot -pstriker --all-databases --routines > C:/alldb.sql' at line 1

***MYSQL Version 5.7.21***

***WampServer Version 3.1.3 64bit***

Could you please any help for this?

***Mysql Command***

```
 mysqldump -uroot -pstriker --all-databases --routines > C:/alldb.sql;
 OR
 mysqldump -uroot -pstriker --all-databases --routines > C:\alldb.sql;
```

Comment: Are you running that on the command line or directly in the mysql client? That command should be run on the command line.

Comment: @aynber. I'm running on mysql console in Wamp Server

Comment: Okay, so yes, that needs to be run on the actual command line, not inside of the mysql client. It's an external mysql command.

Comment: Actually *mysqldump* is a program.

Comment: yes. I knew, it's a program. Even try to windows command prompt. mysqldump.exe -uroot -pstriker --all-databases --routines > C:\alldb.sql;          wamp server->mysql->mysql console->executed command. It's not working. Do you have any ideas how to export all-databases?.

Comment: "It's not working" - Post error message.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel. updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing drive for your dump

```
mysqldump -uroot -pstriker --all-databases --routines > D:\alldb.sql;
```